# Find event date given the probabilities of finding an event

Tags: machine-learning, probability, predictive-models, biostatistics, natural-language

I have a set of clinical notes with dates for each patient and an NLP models which gives a score between 0.0 and 1.0 of a certain event being present in the note. Given the scores, what is the best way to determine the date when the event occurred.

The basic idea is that once the event occurs we will see it mentioned for at least some duration during follow up visits.

A simple way is just to take the first date where we see a high probability, but given the underlying data is not very good, we lose some precision we if we do this. On the other hand, we only consider patients with multiple high probability notes then we miss on some patient who might be new and just had fewer notes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting with probabilities of event, then I don't think you can find the event date. You can find the probability of event taking place on a specific date.

You could model this as [Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process). It might be easier to consider every day, and to track the number of events, since the start of the process, up to and including $i$-th day. Call this number of events $K_i$. Let the daily rate of events between $i$-th and $i-t$-th day be $\Lambda_i$.

Probability of having $n$ events during the period $i-1$...$i$ will be:

$$
P\left[K_i-K_{i-1}=n\right]=\frac{\Lambda_i^n}{n!}\,\exp\left(-\Lambda_i\right)
$$

You could then ask for probability of event on $i-th$ day, and no events on any other day ($0\dots N-1$):

$$
\begin{align}
P\left[\mbox{event on i-th only}\right]&=P\left[K_i-K_{i-1}=1\right]\cdot\Pi_{j\neq i}^{N-1}P\left[K_j-K_{j-1}=0\right] \\
P\left[\mbox{event on i-th only}\right]&=\Lambda_i\cdot\exp\left(-\sum_{s=0}^{N-1}\Lambda_s\right)
\end{align}
$$

You will then need to decide how you want to condition it. But I think the key is that you essentially end up with:

$$
\begin{align}
P\left[\mbox{event on i-th only}\right]&\propto \Lambda_i
\end{align}
$$

Where $\Lambda_i$ describes how many events could happen in a day, and is thus directly related to your probability of an event. So you end up with something like multinational probability of event occurring on different days of your considered period.